# TinyMCE is inactive after installation

Tags: tinymce, activation

Installed TinyMCE, but still getting this toolbar :

https://ps.w.org/tinymce-advanced/assets/screenshot-1.jpg?rev=2390186

instead of this :

https://ps.w.org/tinymce-advanced/assets/screenshot-4.jpg?rev=2390186

what can i do ?

Comment: You should ask the developer of the tinymce-advanced plugin. Third party plugins are off topic here.

Comment: it seems there are Blocks and Classic blocks.. so different menus show up

Comment: Ok? Like I said, contact the plugin developer if the plugin is not working as expected.